# Is it possible to get JSON string directly from MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am wondering if there is a way to get a JSON string directly from the MongoDB with PyMongo or something else. With PyMongo 'db.collection.find' returns a dictionary first and then I have to convert it to JSON with Python's JSON module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDb is BSON not JSON as such I do not believe there is a direct conversion as you see in the console (which is actually converting to JSON the same way you do in python). Converting it later to JSON is your best bet. There have been a few talks about including a __toJSON() function within drivers but the talks normally end with the lines:

"This is better on the client side".

Comment: Thanks, actually if I convert it on the client side, the conversion to JSON is done from the Python dict object. So, BSON->Python Dict and then Python Dict->JSON seems more expensive for the system than BSON->JSON. Also wouldn't converting from BSON to JSON be less expensive than converting from BSON to Python dict?

Comment: @ChrisKoston I am not a Python programmer however I would imagine no due to how JSON strings have to be formed, also I would imagine a dict would be more useful in all other cases where you don't need a JSON string. It is true that a dict most likely holds more resources but a JSON string can be quite expensive to form in any language.